# reledmac: page break before heading in verse stanza

Tags: page-breaking, poetry, reledmac

When typesetting verse with `reledmac`, the command `\ledpb` is supposed to insert a page break at the beginning of the verse line in which it is called.
But if I use the optional argument of `\stanza` to insert a heading, the page break comes after the heading. I would like to keep the heading with the stanza that follows.

If I put `\ledpb` inside the heading `\stanza[\ledpb ...]` then the break is inserted before the previous line of poetry. I think this is because the text in the optional argument to `\stanza` is not counted in the line numbering.

How can I insert a page break before a stanza heading, with no break between the heading and the stanza?

**EDIT:** 
This is perhaps a too-minimal example. I am actually using `reledmac` with `reledpar` for parallel typesetting of verse and translation. There are numerous headers. Inserting manual pagebreaks is really not desirable at all. I have wrapped nearly all of the packages' commands in my own macros like `\StanzaSection{4}[Refrain]` (which sets the stanza indents for a four-line stanza and adds "Refrain" as the header via the optional argument of `\stanza`). I would like to insert something into these commands that prevents a page break after the stanza heading, and/or if possible inserts the option for a pagebreak before the heading, but not a required pagebreak.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}
\stanza[\emph{A}]
Twinkle, twinkle, little star, &
how I wonder what you are. \&

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}
\stanza[\emph{B}]
Up above the world so high, &
like a diamond in the sky, \&

% I would like the page break here, before the heading "A"                                                                                                                
\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}
\stanza[\emph{A}]
Twinkle, twinkle, little star, \ledpb &
how I wonder what you are. \&

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

First page of undesired output in MWE:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you are NOT in parallel typesetting, you can just use the standard \pagebreak.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}
\stanza[\emph{A}]
Twinkle, twinkle, little star, &
how I wonder what you are. \&

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}
\stanza[\emph{B}]
Up above the world so high, &
like a diamond in the sky, \&

% I would like the page break here, before the heading "A"                                                                                                                
\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}
\pagebreak\stanza[\emph{A}]
Twinkle, twinkle, little star,  &
how I wonder what you are. \&

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Also note that, instead of using multiple time `\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}`, just use once time, and use `\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}` (cf § 9.3)

If you use parallel typessetting, the most useful is simply to create more `\begin{pages}` and `\Pages`. page break are automatically inserted before typesetting anything in a `\Pages`.

Comment: Sorry, my example was too minimal. I am actually doing parallel typesetting of verse with its translation.

Comment: see my appendice in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately for a long (5+ pp.) poem with parallel texts, multiple stanza-section headings, and critical footnotes, it will not be practical for me to make the pages manually, without defeating the purpose of using an automated typesetting program. See my edit to the question.

Comment: cf my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking on the way I have implemented `\ledpb`, I remember that I have inserted setting option.

In your case, you must use `\ledpbsetting{after}`.

Cf THIS MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}
\ledpbsetting{after}
\beginnumbering

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}
\stanza[\emph{A}]
Twinkle, twinkle, little star, &
how I wonder what you are. \&

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}
\stanza[\emph{B}]
Up above the world so high, &
like a diamond in the sky, \ledpb\&

% I would like the page break here, before the heading "A"                                                                                                                
\setstanzaindents{0,0,0}
\stanza[\emph{A}]
 Twinkle, twinkle, little star,  &
how I wonder what you are. \&

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: WIth this version I don't get any page break.

Comment: hum… open a github issue, please.